# Using existing liferay login for android

Tags: java, android, cookies, authentication, liferay

I'm modifying a native Java Android app that shows in the phone a liferay website.

The former login was done on a salesforce website, i can reach the user login to mantain the session with the `sid` cookie...

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
// get the cookie containing "sid="
```

Then, when adquired the cookie I know I can redirect to the web without problem and I can mantain the login.

Now, customer wants to change this login and use the existing app's liferay login. I can acceed to liferay website and login but it's not redirecting anywhere, just going to user's profile...

There is a way to catch the success login and then redirect to a private website?

I've tried to import some liferay libraries to create a session as in tutorials:

```
Session session = SettingsUtil.getSession();
```

But I think is not really what I need, cause i don't need a liferay app, just check for success login and redirect to website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Liferay Community**
Liferay quite smart with this, you only need to load the private *home* `URL`, so Liferay will catch the request, keep it, redirect you to login page and when succeed go to original private url mantaining the user login active.

```
webView.loadUrl("/url/to/home");
```

**Liferay Enterprise**
If you try to do it in same way login is not valid and behaviour becomes weird (acting different by devices, emulators and android versions).

After many tests (I hate debugging webviews :@), we've found a workaround: instead of load home url direct, you must include login url and include `?redirect=` in the `webView` load:

```
webView.loadUrl("/url/to/login?redirect=/url/to/home");
```